# initalizing array of vectors in constructor in sfml

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, sfml

I use a SFML library for graphics and other stuff,such as vectors. In my Brain class I try to do something like:

```
class Brain{

Brain(int size){
Vector2f directions[size];
}
}
```

But it throws an error saying it must evaluate to a constant. I tried all sorts of things but I can't get it to compile properly. Anyone knows why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: VLA is not guaranteed in C++.

Comment: Standard c++ doesn't support variable length arrays, hence you need a constant value for `size`. You should use something like `std::vector<Vector2f> directions(size);` instead.

Comment: @Hiroki Not only "not guaranteed", it doesn't exist at all in the C++ specification. If a compiler accepts it, it's as a compiler-specific extension of C++.

Comment: Your problem could easily be solved with [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thx. Yes, GNU compiler supports VLA as an extension even in C90 and C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments in C++ the size of an array must be known at compile time... if you need dynamic containers you can use `std::vector`.

```
class Brain {
public:
    Brain(int size) : _directions{size}
    {
    }

private:
    vector<Vector2d> _directions;
};
```

Don't forget public and private access to your class... By default everything is `private` on a class so in your snippet the contructor of the class is private!